# Como desactivar los checked en una checkbox? javascript

Tags: javascript

Cómo se pueden desactivar los check de una checkbox con una función en javaScript?

```html
<p>
                    <label id="cosas">¿Cuáles de estas has hecho?
                        <br><input type="checkbox" name="check">Abrazar a tus padres
                        <br><input type="checkbox" name="check">Desayunar
                        <br><input type="checkbox" name="check">Hacer ejercicio
                        <br><input type="checkbox" name="check">Comer una golosina
                        <br><input type="checkbox" name="check">Sonreír
                        <br><input type="checkbox" name="check">Jugar play
                    </label>
                </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para desactivar un **`checked`** solo debes poner este código.

```
var checkbox = document.getElementByTagName("check"); // Aqui seleccionas tu checkbox.
checkbox.prop("checked", false); // Aqui le quitas el checked.
```

Answer (score 2):

Unicamente tienes que desactivar la propiedad **`check`** obtienendo el elemento y luego identificas a la propiedad, poniendola en **`false`**. Como dijo Rubén García